# Python - how to send a message through Parse.com to a specific device ID using ParsePy?

Tags: python, push-notification, parse-platform, parsepy

I have a simple web service application that I'm using to test sending pushes through Parse.com from Python.

My app uses Flask module and [ParsePy module](https://github.com/dgrtwo/ParsePy). The code listed below works for the   `Push.alert(notification, channels=["pushDebug"])` - I see a notification on the device subscribed to that channel.

Now I'm trying to send a push to a specific device ID, but am not seeing the notification go through.

**What is the correct syntax to define a "Where" query for a specific user ID (a custom field defined in Parse)?** Here's the line of code that needs this query: `Push.alert(notification, where={"kDeviceID": str(deviceID)})`

Examples I found

```
Push.alert({"alert": "The Mets scored! The game is now tied 1-1.",
            "badge": "Increment", "title": "Mets Score"}, channels=["Mets"],
            where={"scores": True})
```

OR [(taken from parse official documentation)](https://www.parse.com/docs/push_guide#scheduled/REST)

```
"where": {
          "user_id": "user_123"
        }
```

My webservice:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask import Response, jsonify, request, redirect, url_for

from parse_rest.connection import register
from parse_rest.installation import Push

import socket



app = Flask(__name__)
didRegisterWithParse = 0  

def checkRegister():
    if didRegisterWithParse == 0:        
        register(
                 "APPLICATION_ID",
                 "REST_API_KEY",
                 master_key="MASTER_KEY"
                 )
        global didRegisterWithParse
        didRegisterWithParse = 1
        return


  @app.route('/testparsepush/')
    def testparsepush():

        deviceID = request.args.get('device_id')

        hostString = "http://%s:5000/getcommand/" % socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())

        notification = {"alert": "Parse Test","title": "Push from Python", "host": hostString}

        checkRegister()

        # send push notification through parse

        resp = None

        if deviceID:
            Push.alert(notification, where={"kDeviceID": str(deviceID)})
            #prepare response
            resp = jsonify(message = 'sent alert to deviceID: ' + str(deviceID))

        else:
            Push.alert(notification, channels=["pushDebug"])
            resp = jsonify(message = 'sent alert to channel pushDebug')

        resp.status_code = 200
        return resp




if __name__ == '__main__':

    print(socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname()))
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0')
```